# Npgsql and EF error (42703) - column does not exist

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, npgsql

********UPDATE********

The problem persisting occasionaly.  Occurs when I try a insert.
Do anyone have any idea?

```
{"An error occurred while saving entities that do not expose foreign key properties for their relationships. The EntityEntries property will return null because a single entity cannot be identified as the source of the exception. Handling of exceptions while saving can be made easier by exposing foreign key properties in your entity types. See the InnerException for details."}
```

> **InnerException** = *ERRO: 42703: coluna "Convenios_Id" da relação "plano" não existe*

My properties for relationship:

//Convenio Model

```
[Table(name: "convenio", Schema = "public")]
[Serializable]
public class Convenios
{       
    [Key, Column("id")]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Planos> ListaPlanos { get; set; }

    /* ... */
}
```

/* Model Planos */

```
[Table(name: "plano", Schema = "public")]
[Serializable]
public class Planos
{

    [Key, Column("id")]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [Column("convenio_id")]
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "É preciso vincular um convênio a este plano")]
    public int ConvenioId { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("ConvenioId")]
    public virtual Convenios ConvenioVinculado { get; set; }

    /* ... */
}
```

This is a query generated by Npgsql/Entity Framework:

```
(easylabweb%::1(3379)%42700%74)ERRO:  coluna "Convenios_Id" da relaÃ§Ã£o "plano" nÃ£o existe no caracter 421
(easylabweb%::1(3379)%42700%74)COMANDO:  INSERT INTO "public"."plano"    ("convenio_id","descricao","codigo","tabela_id","padrao","percpac","percconv","banda_porte","banda_uco","valch","usuario","status","valfilme","codfilme","codigofilm","motivo","limite","mpercconv","mpercpac","fpercpac","fpercconv","autoriza","deparapla","valorauto","autori","ambobriga","descmat","obs","tipotab","valcopart","dtultger","operador_id_ultger","marca","dtultgerini","dtultgerfin","Convenios_Id") VALUES (0,E'Qui et eum soluta sed et expedita',NULL,cast(177 as int8),1,25,75,35,65,cast(30 as numeric),NULL,0,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,8,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,1,NULL,NULL,E'Eos, modi deserunt beatae et eveniet, mollitia omnis voluptate nulla eiusmod labore.',2,61,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,cast(5143 as int8));
SELECT currval(pg_get_serial_sequence('"public"."plano"', 'id')) AS "id"
(easylabweb%::1(3379)%00000%74)LOG:  duraÃ§Ã£o: 0.000 ms  comando: ROLLBACK
```

I don't have idea about this problem...

****END UPDATE****

I'm use **Npgsql** version 2.1.3.0 and everything was working fine until this error started happening today and I can not find the reason for this.

(column does not exist)

```
InnerException  {"ERRO: 42703: coluna Extent1.Planos_Id não existe"}    System.Exception {Npgsql.NpgsqlException}
```

This is the code generated by **Npgsql**

```
select 'Npgsql12322'
(easylabweb%::1(64263)%42700%74)ERRO:  coluna Extent1.Planos_Id não existe no caracter 142
(easylabweb%::1(64263)%42700%74)COMANDO:  SELECT "Extent1"."id" AS "id","Extent1"."exame_id" AS "exame_id","Extent1"."plano_id" AS "plano_id","Extent1"."convenio_id" AS "convenio_id","Extent1"."Planos_Id" AS "Planos_Id" FROM "public"."descoberto" AS "Extent1" WHERE ("Extent1"."Planos_Id" IS NOT NULL ) AND ("Extent1"."Planos_Id"= (((5179))))
(easylabweb%::1(64263)%00000%74)LOG:  duração: 0.000 ms  comando: DISCARD ALL
(easylabweb%::1(64263)%00000%74)LOG:  duração: 0.000 ms  comando: SET extra_float_digits=3;
```

This is my model:

```
[Serializable]
[Table(name:"descoberto", Schema= "public")]
public class ExmDescobertos
{
    public ExmDescobertos()
    {
        var bytes = Identificador.ToByteArray();
        if (!bytes.Any(b => b != 0))
            Identificador = Guid.NewGuid();
    }

    [NotMapped]
    public Guid Identificador { get; private set; }

    [Key, Column("id")]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [Column("exame_id")]
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Informe o exame")]
    public int ExameId { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("ExameId")]
    [Display(Name = "Exame", Description = "Exame")]
    public virtual Exames Exame { get; set; }

    [Column("plano_id")]
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Informe o plano")]
    public int PlanoId { get; set; }

    [Column("convenio_id")]
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Informe o Convênio")]
    public int ConvenioId { get; set; }
```

Thanks for your help

Comment: Did you ever get an answer to this?

Comment: No! But I'm not working with this task more...

Comment: I can't close this topic